# When I click on my div I don't want it effecting all the divs with the same class?

Tags: jquery

originally when I clicked on my div the caption slides up but it affected all the other divs with the same class as well. I just want it to effect the div that's being clicked on. So I tried this option below but it didn't work at all! Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bubble").click(function() {
        $(this).find('.slide-up').slideToggle(1000);              
    });

});

<div class="property">  
<div class="left-column">       
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/test-image.jpg" width="670px" height="450px" />       
    <div class="bubble"></div>      
    <div class="slide-up"><h1>CHARM? LOCATION? AWESOME? CHECK, CHECK AND CHECK</h1></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: you can post your html ....

Comment: How could someone help you if you don't post relevant HTML code???

Comment: what about it isn't working at all?

Comment: Next time post relevant HTML code because now all answers are no more accurate except pXL & Abel Pastur ones...

Comment: Make --^ 4 votes. Who makes the combo complete? :) `$(this).find('.slide-up')`. The find tries to find something within the current element. Use `next` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bubble").click(function() {
        $(this).next('.slide-up').slideToggle(1000);              
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.next` *as your `slide-up` div is next to `bubble` not inside of it*

```
$(".bubble").click(function() {
        $(this).next('.slide-up').slideToggle(1000);              
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the event to get the one you want.

```
$(".bubble").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).find('.slide-up').slideToggle(1000);              
});
```

Comment: Fair enough... But in this case the object he is clicking is the target. As indicated by `$(this)`

Comment: Yes, your code makes sense. But would be better if OP let us see what he is looking for

Comment: this will fail, if someone click's on `.slide-up` as target will be the `.slide-up` itself

Answer (score 0):

If you have many '.bubble' elements; `$('.bubbles')` returns an array of elements which, when a click event is triggered will execute over all bubbles.

What you need to do is iterate over each element and assign it's own click event using:

```
$(".bubble").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).find('.slide-up').slideToggle(1000);              
    })
});
```

I've created a working example for you here - http://jsfiddle.net/CGWGreen/acGLX/. Cheers GW